# Custom text in front of image

Tags: javascript, php, image, image-processing

I found [this site](https://www.evermine.com/baby_announcements/preview/NAVB40-04/) and worry about how to build a simple page to **replace** text with another custom text inside the image using either backend language (ex. PHP) or frontend using javascript. Please fisit the link to get big picture about what I need.

Can someone tell what library should I use?

[image]

Comment: Either ImageMagic or GD Library.  Start [link]here (http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)

Comment: yes, I know that library. but how to mark that text is editable or not? how to know that I replace the text in same layer.

Comment: You would want a client side process for that.  I use JQuery and Javascript to make text changeable.  Then pass the artwork to a control script for processing.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done easily with the GD library and some class for easy work with it like PHPImageWorkshop. GD library is a base for php above a certain version (not remember which one), and does not need installation. Class could be download from here - http://phpimageworkshop.com/

```php
<?php
    require_once 'lib/WideImage.php';

    $text = mysql_escape_string($_POST['text']);        

    $image = WideImage::load('image.jpg')->resize(500);         

    if ($text != Null || $text != "" )  {
        $canvas = $image->getCanvas();      
        $canvas->useFont('someFont.ttf', 55, $image->allocateColor(255, 255, 255));
        $canvas->writeText("center", "bottom", "$text");
    }

    $image = $image->saveToFile('newImage.jpg'); 
?>
```

Comment: I think this is far for the requirement. You need to visit the URL above and check how the web actually work. There is an initial text that should be replaced, not just put text on blank of area.

Comment: The above example, does just that. First image is basic (image.jpg), without text and it generate another image with another name which includes the text (newImage.jpg). In The example, new image is overwritten when the code execute and it is what you want.

Comment: one more tip, when show newImage.jpg in html, add time variable to avoid caching of image from browser.
<img sec=<?php echo "newImage.jpg?".time(); ?> />